# how to set an image from url to imageview on widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-volley

how to set an image from url to imageview on widget ?

I think the best way is to use volley lib :

```
    ImageLoader imageLoader = MyVolley.getImageLoader();

       imageLoader.get("http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/upload/yuu1.jpg", new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {

                remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img_view_main_image_widgets,response.getBitmap());  
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```

but my imageview will be white color !

---

**updated :**

I've tested it on another project and it worked fine(a simple imageview).

```
    final ImageView two = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.two);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = MyVolley.getImageLoader();

       imageLoader.get("http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/upload/yuu1.jpg", new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {

                two.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());

            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```

but I added a log and I got error :

> 01-21 17:28:41.801: E/error(2855): error

```
       imageLoader.get("http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/upload/yuu1.jpg", new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {

                remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img_view_main_image_widgets,response.getBitmap());
                if(response.getBitmap() == null){
                    Log.e("error", "error");
                }
            }
```

---

**updated :**

All my code :

http://pastebin.com/0wi4pX0N

I just get :

> 01-21 17:50:41.066: E/getBitmap(13554): getBitmap

```
       imageLoader.get("http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/upload/yuu1.jpg", new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {


                if(response == null){
                    Log.e("response", "response");
                }else if (response.getBitmap() == null){
                    Log.e("getBitmap", "getBitmap");
                }else{
                    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img_view_main_image_widgets,response.getBitmap());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is `R.id.img_view_main_image_widgets` correct? Is `response` correct? Is `response.getBitmap()` not null?

Comment: yes, it is null ! why ?! updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed your `Bitmap` is `null`. Here is your error.

Why it is `null` is another one: your network call just return no `Bitmap`, so nothing is displayed...

Always check for `null`s:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
    if (response == null) {
        // FAILURE
        return ;
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = response.getBitmap();
    if (bitmap != null) {
        // SUCCESS
        // setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else {
        // FAILURE
        // display placeholder or whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Another NPE? Where? You said `Bitmap` was null. Check if `response` is also null...

Comment: response is not null ! just bitmap is null ! :-?

Comment: Yes, I got it. You have to understand that you application does not crash anymore. The call you're doing is just returning a null `Bitmap`. That I cannot debug. I just explained to you where that `NullPointerException` came from.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.shadyab.com/assests/images/upload/yuu1.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```